# Intersection of all powers of prime ideals in a Noetherian ring is $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative ring. Show that $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} \bigcap_{\mathfrak p \in \mathrm{Spec}(R)}\mathfrak p^n = \{0\}.$$

I definitely want to use Krull intersection theorem as $\bigcap_{p \in Spec(R)}p^n $ is inside the jacobson radical. So I want to find some ideal $J$ in the jacobson radical such that for every $n$, there exists $n_i$ such that $\bigcap_{p \in Spec(R)}p^n \subset J^{n_i} $, then the result applies. Right know I am thinking of letting $J$ be the nipotent radical, but I'm not sure if this is valid. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can also view the intersection in every localization of $R$ (where you can apply Krull!)

Comment: @Mindlack I believe localization only commutes with finite intersection. How can I apply localization when the intersection is infinite

Comment: Sure, it doesn’t *per se* commute, but there’s still a useful inclusion working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/18850/121097) it is mentioned the following useful result: if $x\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}I^n$, then $x\in xI$, that is, there is $a\in I$ such that $(1-a)x=0$. One uses this result for a prime ideal $P$, and get an element outside of $P$ which multiplied by $x$ gives zero. When this happens for *all* primes we can conclude that $x=0$.

Comment: So, it seems that we can deduce for all maiximal $P$, the result still holds?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could also think about this in terms of primary decompositions.

Since $R$ is Noetherian, $0$ has a primary decomposition $0 = \bigcap Q_i$.

Since $P_i = \sqrt{Q_i}$ is finitely generated, there exists $n_i$ such that $P_i^{n_i} \subseteq Q_i$.  Therefore $\bigcap P_i^{n_i} = 0$